# Mapkit in Xcode 6 only shows overlays west of dateline when zoomed in (using Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, polyline

I've spent probably about 6 hours researching and trial & error'ing this problem and am in a bind - help!

I'm creating a simple set of longitudinal polylines around the world, and find strange behaviour when the date line (antimeridian) is visible at 180degrees E/W in view. If fully zoomed out, all the polylines display correctly, but once I start zooming in, the lines east of the antimeridian start to disappear.  If I zoom back out, the lines reappear.  Or, if I pan the map so the antmeridian/date line is just off the left edge of the view, all the lines also reappear (regardless of zoom level)! I'm showing 4 screenshots below:

- (not shown)Span at approx. 108 degrees and above (all polylines visible)
- Span at 101 degrees (my polylines east of the date line start disappearing)
  [image: 101 degrees]
- Span at 92 degrees (more lines disappeared)
  [image: 92 degrees]
- Span at 81 degrees (all polylines east of date line have disappeared)
  [image: 81 degrees]
- Span at 82 with date line just off the left edge of view (all polylines reappear) // Ignore that the lines look thinner on this screenshot - I had been playing with the line thickness
  [image: 82 degrees]

My code is below. The drawgrid() function gets called on every region update.  This happens identically in both the iOS 8 + iPhone 6 simulator as well as a real device (iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1)

```
func drawgrid() {
    var b: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []    
    for var x = -179.99; x <= 179.99; x = x + 1.0 { // I tried -180.0 to 180.0 as well -> no effect     
        let c1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90.0, longitude: x) // Tried 80.0 as well
        let c2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90.0, longitude: x) // Tried -80.0 as well
        b = [c1, c2]
        var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &b, count: b.count)
        mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays) // Already tried commenting this out (it's for a different purpose elsewhere in the app)
    drawgrid()
    MyLabel.text = "Span = \(mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta) deg"
    MyLabel2.text = "Center = \(mapView.region.center.longitude) \(mapView.region.center.latitude)"
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    if overlay is MKPolyline{
        var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 0.1 // tried thicker value of 1.0 too
        return polylineRenderer
    }
    return nil
}
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated! I'm a bit of a noob (just started coding a few weeks ago) so if you can provide guidance in Swift instead of Objective-C that would save me from banging my head against the desk a bit too. Thank you!

EDIT 11/22/2014: Still having this problem and it seems that it affects not just overlays but annotations as well.  As long as the international date line is in the view, all my annotations disappear, regardless of where they exist on the map.. Still haven't been able to find a way around this and it truly is smelling like a bug..

Comment: Can you show us your view did load so we can see how everything is initialised also can you post pic of what it should look like?

Comment: Got it now if i had to guess the problems in that for loop declaration

Comment: This is a still a problem in iOS 9.2.1 with Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Add the following println().

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    println("region did change*****************************") // Added
    mapView.removeOverlays(mapView.overlays) // Already tried commenting this out (it's for a different purpose elsewhere in the app)
    drawgrid()
    MyLabel.text = "Span = \(mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta) deg"
    MyLabel2.text = "Center = \(mapView.region.center.longitude) \(mapView.region.center.latitude)"
}
```

And

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {





    if overlay is MKPolyline{
        var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 1 // tried thicker value of 1.0 too
        println("Lonitude " + "\(overlay.coordinate.longitude)") //Added
        return polylineRenderer
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then run your app and look at the console box, you'll see thee values appearing like normal until you get to the problem area then the negative longitudes get cut off at a point.

Looking up the reference for the renderForOverlay function. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/addOverlays: it says that polylines who's bounding intersects the view portion of the map it will be rendered(which I take it those that do not will not be rendered). I believe this might be your problem.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to the problem but it was a bit long winded to put as a comment

Comment: Thanks Conor.  The additional comments in the console confirm what I'm seeing, though unfortunately doesn't provide me any insight as to why the lines aren't being rendered.  The same lines that are missing from the view are missing from the console output as well.  Does this indicate that when I call mapView.addOverlay(polyline) that the renderForOverlay delegate isn't being called?  Any idea why this might be the case? The lines are definitely intersecting my view so I'm still puzzled.